# HTML displaced select options

Tags: html, css, debugging, firefox, flexbox

The code below seems to be working on the first sight, however FF (currently testing on FF26) is displacing the select options and not working afterwards (unable to choose the option). No problems in Chrome 35. Is this a FF bug, maybe partial support for flexbox, etc. ?

HTML

```
<div class="order-item-new">
 <select id="item" class="select" form="order-form" name="order[]">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.order-item-new
{
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    -moz-box-flex: 0;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 18%, rgba(61, 145, 153, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 84%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 45px;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.order-item-new select
{
    -moz-box-flex: 0;
    flex: 0 1 120px;
    margin: 7px 10px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wJ4H9/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), Firefox 30 and later support flexbox, but earlier versions do not.

Comment: From caniuse.com: 3. Does not support flex-wrap or flex-flow properties. There are no such properties in my CSS however.

Comment: There have been numerous different flexbox specifications - the two properties you mention are from the 2012 spec.